# Trendline in excel on min max values

Tags: excel, regression, trendline

I have series of data around 3000 rows. x values are angle, y power. So a cloud is created with max min and average values all over the place (check image attached).

If I use the trend-line option of excel it draws as it should a trend line that matches the median values BUT I want to draw a trend line, on the maximum and another one on the minimum values only. Is there a way to do that?

Thx

[image: Photo]

Comment: Add two more columns for Max and Min. Then add a trendline to each data series

Comment: Ron, i did that but the result is not good, isnt there a way to get the outer trend lines in excel automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "not good"?  Without also seeing a sample of your data, hard to make any more suggestions. But I don't know another method of plotting a trendline. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable about graphing can answer.  If you do add a data sample to your question, **please** add it as text that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Min and the Max values to the chart as new series. Add a trend line for each of these series.

Next, format the data series for Min and Max to have no fill, no line, no markers, so they become invisible and don't upset your chart display. That leaves only the trendlines visible.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.